# Anotating mean values on a distribution frequency

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a grupal frequency distribution plots and anotate the mean value. Most direct way is:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
load(mtcars)
mtcars0=mtcars%>%group_by(cyl)%>%mutate(MeanMpg=round(mean(mpg),2))
mtcars1=mtcars%>%group_by(cyl)%>%summarize(MeanMpg=round(mean(mpg),2))
p <- ggplot(mtcars0, aes(mpg, fill=cyl)) +
  facet_wrap(. ~ cyl) + 
  geom_density(alpha=.2) +
  geom_vline(data=mtcars1, aes(xintercept=MeanMpg), linetype="dashed", size=1) +
  annotate("text", label = labels, size = 4, x = 15, y = 0.26)
p
```

[image]

the problem shows when i want to put mean values exactly on the middle of the mean line:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars0, aes(mpg, fill=cyl)) +
  facet_wrap(. ~ cyl) + 
  geom_density(alpha=.2) +
  geom_vline(data=mtcars1, aes(xintercept=MeanMpg), linetype="dashed", size=1) +
  annotate("text", label = labels, size = 4, x = mtcars1$MeanMpg, y = 0.26)
> p
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (9): label
```

[image]

Ihn this case R multiply the text and i get an error.
    How I can achive to put the label on each mean position in the facets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your `mtcars1` data to specify the position of the labels:

```
ggplot(mtcars0, aes(mpg, fill=cyl)) +
  facet_wrap(. ~ cyl) + 
  geom_density(alpha=.2) +
  geom_vline(data = mtcars1, aes(xintercept = MeanMpg), linetype="dashed", size=1) +
  geom_text(data = mtcars1, aes(x = MeanMpg, y = 0.25, label = MeanMpg))
```

[image]